# Using index.html in their own folder for each page to get clean URLs

Tags: web, seo, directory-structure, clean-urls

I was wondering if their was anything wrong with making each webpage as an index.html in its own folder to achieve clean URLs. You just link to the directory and the index.html is automatically served without a mod_rewrite. For example instead of having:

```
 .
 |-about.html     url: example.com/about.html
 |-contact.html   url: example.com/contact.html
 |-index.html     url: example.com
```

you could have:

```
 .
 |-about
 |    \-index.html   url: example.com/about/
 |-contact
 |    \-index.html   url: example.com/contact/
 |-index.html        url: example.com/
```

I couldn't find any good search results about this. Is their any problems with doing something like this that I haven't foreseen? What about SEO?

Answer (score 1):

it's easier to create domain.com/contact.html and truncate .html with .htaccess file so your URL would be domain.com/contact - no need to create folders

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to crawl a clean URL.

When Google crawls your internal links, it will result in 404 error page as shown below.

http://www.sample.com/xyz.html/category/abc.html

With the use of absolute links, you are avoiding this type of situation.

IE: http://www.sample.com/xyz